# Dispose() on asp.net pages

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.NET web site and I get a session id from a web service where I am going to use throughout rest of pages.  I am passing this session id between pages to peform some action.  What I am trying to achieve is that I want to make sure I release this session id from the web service by calling it's logout method when the user closes a page.  I am thinking to add Dispose() on each page and call the logout method.  Does Dispose() get called when the user closes a page (browser)?  Or, how can I call the logout method when a page is closed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dispose will get called at the end of each page call, not at the end of the user's session.  It sounds to me like you want to use the Session_End event (in the global.asax) to end the web service session.  If you call the logout in the page dispose you'll have to login again every time the user loads a new page.

Comment: Okay, thanks for this.  I read some posts that this will only work with inproc.